# How to add add multiple object into a same index

Tags: javascript, object, variable-assignment

I wanted to create a multi dimensional object. Below is my sample code. I'm not very familiar in JavaScript.

**Sample code**

```
var test = {};

test[0] = {1:{a:1,b:2,c:3}};

if(true)
{
  test[0] = {2: {c:1,b:2,a:3}};
}

console.log(test);
```

**Expecting result**

```
{
  0: {
       1:{a:1,b:2,c:3},
       2:{c:1,b:2,a:3}  
     }
}
```

Comment: `test[0][2] = {c:1,b:2,a:3};`

Comment: It will return undefined index 2

Comment: @d3no No it won't...

Comment: No it won't. [It will give you the expected result.](https://jsfiddle.net/Lspet9jx/)

Comment: Thank for help bro, finally work now. I tot should do with test[0][1] too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second time you set `test[0]`, you're overwriting it completely.  To do exactly what you're looking for, you'd use:

```
test[0][2] = {c:1,b:2,a:3};
```

Depending on what you're doing though, you might consider an array `[]` or Set instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can Try this :

```
var obj = { 
  0: { 
    1:{a:1,b:2,c:3},
    2:{c:1,b:2,a:3} 
  }
} ;
// to access :
alert(obj[0][1].b);
// Or
alert(obj[0][1]["b"]);
```

Run and test it in [here](https://jsbin.com/sixabayuju/edit?js).